What was the first Anime TV Series that was released on Blu-ray (or HD-DVD)?
I remember Kure-nai (2008) to be the first anime TV show that I experienced on Blu-ray, but what was the actual first TV series that got produced and released with Blu-ray in mind?

Not quite a duplicate (since it's asking about TV series and the other post mostly covers movies), but there was some discussion about early Blu-Ray releases here: What was the first anime to come out on Bluray/HDDVD?

Following the link from the related question to the page for Blu-Ray releases, it's possible to look at anime releases by release date, but you have to first change the country of release to Japan or else you'll be looking at all the American releases which is not a great indicator. Once you do that, the first few TV series I could find were:

AIR (Dec 22, 2006) (thanks to sundowner for the catch)

Utawarerumono (Jan 23, 2008)

Afro Samurai: Season One (Director's Cut) (Feb 8, 2008)

Bus Gamer (Mar 21, 2008)

Full Metal Panic! Season One (Jun 27, 2008)

Ghost in the Shell: S.A.C. Trilogy (Jul 25, 2008) (technically OVAs cut from the actual series)

Macross Frontier Vol. 1 (Jul 25, 2008)

Code Geass Lelouch of the Rebellion Vol. 1 (Aug 22, 2008)


Of these, both Afro Samurai and Bus Gamer were originally released post-2006 and so could in theory have been produced with a Blu-ray release in mind. The others all pre-date Blu-ray by a few years so definitely could not have been made with such a release in mind. Both shows are short, at five and three episodes respectively.
The first full-length TV series I could find (i.e. 10 or more episodes) with a production date after 2006 was Mobile Suit Gundam 00, whose first Blu-ray came out on August 22, 2008, and whose Wikipedia article claims was the first Gundam series to be animated in high definition so even if it wasn't specifically made with Blu-ray in mind that might be the best we can get.

Utawarerumono is a 2006 anime, though. It might have gotten a BD release early on (which answers part of my question), but that was an upscale. It wasn't produced with BD in mind. This seems to be the case with Afro Samurai, Bus Gamer, FMP, GitS, Macross Frontier and Code Geass, too.

The question in the title just asks for first series on Blu-ray, but in the body asks for first one produced for Blu-ray, so I tried to answer both.

This says the first is an anime called AIR, which was released 2006/12.

@sundowner Good find. It's even on the list, but I missed it when scanning. I'll add it to my post.
